# Bootstrap's .thumbnail class is adding mysterious top padding, on mobile only - but I can't fathom out why

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a temporary link to the page where I'm encountering the problem: http://shoutkey.com/squeeze

If you resize your browser down to a mobile layout width, you'll see the thumbnail image container suddenly is far too high with extra padding at the top. But I can't for the life of me work out why this is - there are no CSS rules that appear to do this, `height` is set to `auto`, etc.

Any ideas?

This screenshot shows it working **correctly**, in large browsers:

[image: correct display]

And this screenshot shows it in mobile browsers - **notice all the excess padding at the top**:

[image: incorrect display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't coming from bootstrap.  that space is being taken up by your `.news-author` divs, but you have either some float/clear issues or some unclosed tags, etc. causing it to interact strangely with the `.thumbnail` div below it.  you can see what's happening by adding either `.news-author {display:none}` or removing the `background:#fff` from `.thumbnail`

Edit: You can fix it by adding class 'clearfix' on your `col-md-4` div that contains the headline and author info.

Comment: I did run validation to check for unclosed tags, but there weren't any. But your `clearfix` has solved things. Thanks so much!